# Wie setze ich Demonstrativpronomen in diesem Satz korrekt ein?

Tags: subordinate-clause, demonstrative-pronoun

> Es gibt viele Menschen die dich einfach nur deiner Seele wegen, aus tiefster heraus lieben werden.

Is there a word I can use before or after *tiefster*, which refers to *Seele*? - as in

> Es gibt viele Menschen die dich einfach nur deiner Seele wegen, aus ebendieser  heraus, zutiefst lieben werden.
>   <sub>ebendieser / ihrer / dieser</sub>

Neither looks sound to me. Is there a way I can write the first sentence without using *Seele* twice; is it possible to omit the pronoun?

Comment: Could you please tell, what exactly you try to express? I guess, you want to simplify the sentence *Es gibt viele Menschen, die dich einfach nur deiner Seele wegen, aus tiefster Seele heraus lieben werden.* and replace the second occurrence of *Seele*. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I wanted to be asking. @Arsak

Comment: Kein Demonstrativpronomen, daher nur als Kommentar: ich würde *aus tiefstem **Herzen** heraus* schreiben.

Comment: Thank you  @ Arsak that's what I had in mind as well (: - for me it makes a difference though. When I love someone from my heart, that's a feeling that might change one day. When I love someone from my soul, then that's something that will never change again.

Comment: I personally never thought of this distinction, but I understand what you mean. :) However, I think replacing the second *Seele* with a demonstrative pronoun (as in your example) bears the risk of confusion - as if *you* are loving someone from the depth of *their* soul.

Comment: :) - That's a good point, I didn't think about it that way, maybe that's the reason it doesn't sound quite right when you read it aloud. The pronoun indeed refers to "*their soul*" as object, since the previous clause defines it as "*deiner Seele*". Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One additional possibility (to ebendieser etc.) would be "selbiger". But none of these constructions sound good in this particular sentence. I would change the order of the parts:

> Es gibt viele Menschen, die Dich aus tiefster Seele (heraus) lieben werden, einfach nur der Deinen wegen.

The "heraus" is possible but not necessary - therefore I put it in parenthesis.

Edit:
Arsaks Kommentar unter der Frage ist auch ein guter Hinweis: Statt *aus tiefster Seele* könnte man *aus tiefstem Herzen* schreiben, dann kann *Deiner Seele wegen* so bleiben, ohne dass es eine Doppelung gibt.

Comment: Das hört sich schön an, Danke, genau so habe ich mir diesen Satz vorgestellt! :)